# Android : Spinner OnSelectedItemListener

Tags: android, listview

I have an application with a ListView that displays different transactions made by the user. My code doesn't seem to work.

The problem I have now is that I want to add a Spinner above this ListView to let the user choose whether the transactions should be ordered by date, amount or an own choice of an interval between two dates.

Heres my code for just the spinner onSelectedItem:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income, container, false);
        initializeComponents(view);
        registerListeners();
        spinnerOrderIncome = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOrderIncome);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.spinnerSortIncome, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerOrderIncome.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerOrderIncome.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (spinnerOrderIncome.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                    case "date":
                        lvIncome.setAdapter(new CustomIncomeListAdapter(activity, dbController.getDataFromIncomeTable()));
                        break;
                    case "amount":
                        lvIncome.setAdapter(new CustomIncomeListAdapter(activity, dbController.getSortedAmountFromIncomeTable()));
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

The ListView is already populated with this method that gets the list from the DatabaseController:

```
public void populateListView() {
        lvIncome.setAdapter(new CustomIncomeListAdapter(activity, dbController.getDataFromIncomeTable()));
    }
```

The methods are seen in the switch-statement where thought to change the order of the ListView, but nothing happens when I select the different spinner items (date, amount) Am I on the right track? Help!

Comment: Yes, you are on track, whenever you make a selection from the spinner, the content inside of the ListView will be changed based on the order of the data set you pass into CustomIncomeListAdapter.

Comment: Please edit the question, whether you ran into problem? or You just need to ensure on the track,  Is it working or not! To me everything seems right!!

Comment: The ting is that now when I run the code it does nothing for me, the ListView doesn't change when the different methods are called? Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you debugged the code and stepped through it to make sure the onItemSelected callback is firing?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it and the selections are being made, it seems that the lvIncome.setAdapter doesn't work :/

Comment: I don't see the code where you are connecting your ListView reference with the xml via a findViewById(...).

Comment: I initialize my components in a method that I haven't posted here. But it IS initialized

Comment: @JensO.AndersOlsén when you say it doesn't work what exactly do you mean? Is it crashing, is nothing displaying or do you see the exact same content?

Comment: The same content is shown, but when I but a Logd when the item is selected it is shown... so when I set the adapter with the method call to the database controller, nothing happens.

Comment: Could the content between the two list you are passing into the CustomIncomeListAdapter be the same? Maybe that is why it appears nothing is happening because it's the same data before and after. Debug through the code and view the data being passed in and check to see if the list's elements patch between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a new adapter to the listView each time you change its data, I would just update the list it contains, then call notifyDataSetChanged to inform the adapter that its datased has changed (so the view will be redrawn).

Something like that, I guess (not tested) :

```
spinnerOrderIncome.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CustomIncomeListAdapter myAdapter = (CustomIncomeListAdapter)lvIncome.getAdapter();
        myAdapter.getDataSet().clear();
        switch (spinnerOrderIncome.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
            case "date":
                myAdapter.getDataSet().addAll(dbController.getDataFromIncomeTable());
                break;
            case "amount":
                myAdapter.getDataSet().addAll(dbController.getSortedAmountFromIncomeTable());
                break;
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will add data to the data set, he seems to want to rearrange the content. Probably should expose a clear or replaceData method on the adapter.

Comment: I did the clear just before the switch : myAdapter.getDataSet().clear();
I forgot to mention tha the "getDataSet() method should be created and return the dataSet.

Comment: ahh, I see now. Sorry!

Comment: @Pat The getDataSet-method, what's your thoughts on it I don't really understand this bit!? :)

Comment: @Jens O. Anders Olsén you have to manually add the getDataSet method to your adapter and will return Adapter's data set object so you can call addAll on it.

Comment: @Jens O. Anders Olsén Your CustomIncomeListAdapter constructor is made this way : CustomIncomeListAdapter(Context context, SomeType dataset). In your CustomIncomeListAdapter class, you need to create a method getDataSet() that will return the dataset you passed to the constructor, so you can manipulate it outside the adapter class.

Comment: @Jens O. Anders Olsén Or you can also create a method "replaceDataSet" (in your adapter) that will take the new dataSet in parameter and will perform the clear and the addAll.

Comment: @Pat Do you mean a method that is "public ArrayList<IncomeModel> getIncomeList { return incomeList; ?

Comment: @Jens O. Anders Olsén Yes, this is exactly what I mean :).

Comment: That for some reason didn't work... and the select statements from the two different methods in the databaseController should work as well?! It's just a normal ("SELECT * FROM "+ TableIncome.TABLE_NAME + " order by " +  TableIncome.INCOME_AMOUNT + " DESC ", null), when it comes to the amount sorting.

Comment: Do your methods in dbController return the expected values ? When you debug the app, is your debugger stepping into the cases you have in your switch ? Did you not forgot "myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" ?

Comment: It steps into the switch, already debugged that. And no I didn't forgot the notifyDataSetChanged :)

Comment: Well I guess your problem is located elsewhere in your project, if after the notifyDataSetChanged, the data in myAdapter.getDataSet() is correct, maybe you change it later in your project. Try debugging the getView method of your adapter which is called each time your adapter has to redraw the list.